# Travis CI setup failed - "Couldn't set project path to: xxx"

Tags: github, unity-game-engine, travis-ci

I am trying to set up a Travis CI server to build my Unity3D project from my **private** github repository. I tried following the guide found at https://jonathan.porta.codes/2015/04/17/automatically-build-your-unity3d-project-in-the-cloud-using-travisci-for-free/, but since I only want to build for Windows I narrowed the build.sh file down to

```
echo "Attempting to build $project for Windows"
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -silent-crashes \
  -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log \
  -projectPath $(pwd) \
  -buildWindowsPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/windows/$project.exe" \
  -quit

echo 'Logs from 
cat $(pwd)/unity.log
```

But my "build.sh" scripts gives me the error

```
Couldn't set project path to: /Users/travis/build/Nikzer/BAC16109TravisTest
(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Utilities/Argv.cpp Line: 171)
```

Where "Nikzer/BAC16109TravisTest" is the repo name.

I tried different solutions such as changing *pwd* to *PWD* which was used in some other answer, but this does not work either.

I hope someone is able to help me in some way :) Thanks

***(First StackOverflow post btw guys)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-projectPath` argument requires an equals sign between `-projectPath` and the path in older Unity versions.
E.g.: `-projectPath=$(pwd)`

This has been fixed in a Unity version released after Unity 2018.1.3